# Zooming the map after filter

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have wms layer and after i do cql filter on this. And now i want to see result. I want map zoomed to this result. My code.

```
ex=layer.getExtent();
map.zoomToExtent(ex);
```

But getExtent() returns wrong bounds. In Geoserver i have layer settings

```
Native SRS=70066
Declared SRS=900913
Reproject native to declared
```

In OL when create map i write projection: EPSG 900913;

What im doing wrong? I ll try do transformation

```
ex=layer.getExtent().transformation(map.projection, map.displayProjection);
```

projection=70066
displayProjection=900913

But it nothig to change.

Maybe im gonna do it whis Capabilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to zoom map after CQL_Filter?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25647/how-to-zoom-map-after-cql-filter)

Comment: yes, i was read this. But there another way to solve this problem. If this is possible i want use getExtent.

Comment: see my answer to the linked question.

Comment: My english is bad, but if im understad u its mean that im gonna do WFS layer and use getDataExtent()?

Comment: that's right a WMS Layer is jsut a picture and it has the bounds that you have set in the request

Comment: tnx for answer. But i want ask what return getExtent(). Its return bound, but bound of what?

Comment: the bounds of the map object.

Comment: wms = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities();
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/filedata?request=GetCapabilities",
    success: function(e){
        var response = wms.read(e.responseText);
var capability = response.capability;
for (var i=0, len=capability.layers.length; i<len; i+=1) { 
    var layerObj = capability.layers[i]; 
    if (layerObj.name === 'filedata') { 
        map.zoomToExtent(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(layerObj.llbbox)); 
        break; 
    } 
}
    }
});

Comment: Sorry, cant faid code tag. Ill get llbox in lon lat, but zoomToExtent dont working why?