# How to get BBOX from WMS GetCapabilities response?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, getcapabilities

I have a WMS layer and want use zoomToExtent after CQL filter. So I get the layer BBOX from the GeoServer WMS using a GetCapabilities request.

```
wms = new OpenLayers.Format.WMSCapabilities();
OpenLayers.Request.GET({
  url:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/filedata?request=GetCapabilities",
  success: function(e){
    var response = wms.read(e.responseText);
    var capability = response.capability;
    for (var i=0, len=capability.layers.length; i<len; i+=1) { 
      var layerObj = capability.layers[i]; 
      if (layerObj.name === 'filedata') { 
        map.zoomToExtent(OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray(layerObj.llbbox)); 
        break; 
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

But zoomToExtent doesn't work with lon lat, so how to get the BBOX in meters?

My map showed in epsg900913.

Comment: The answer is the same as your previous question - [Zooming the map after filter](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25715/zooming-the-map-after-filter) WMS doesn't work the way that you seem to think.

Comment: in last time im ask this question uncorrectly. But today i see project when its worc fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use **transform** method for getting your result in meters.

```
OpenLayers.Projection.transform = function( point,
    source,
    dest    )
```

> Transform a point coordinate from one projection to another.  Note
>   that the input point is transformed in place.

**Parameters**

> point {{OpenLayers.Geometry.Point> | Object} An object with x and y
>   properties
>           representing coordinates in those dimensions.
>
> sourceProj    {OpenLayers.Projection} Source map coordinate system
>
> destProj  {OpenLayers.Projection} Destination map coordinate system

**Example :**

```
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-3.57138, 39.8384);
    lonlat.transform(map.displayProjection, map.baseLayer.projection);
    map.setCenter(lonlat, 5);
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Strange thing. i get correct bbox in lon lat. After transform i get meters bbox its correct too. But when use zoomToExtent nothing heppens. Im add Controls.MousePosition and mouse show that my map out of extent which i get. Whats wrong?

Comment: And another question if i have only polygons im must use setCenter()?

Comment: try to get bobunding box center lon-lat. example: `map.getExtent().getCenterLonLat()`...then set it to center...

Comment: transform(projection,displayProjection)  dont working. Try convert lonlat in meters but its not heppening.

Comment: can you share your error you have met? in normal situation it works very well

Comment: I dont get any error text, its just not transform projections. But in Geoserver console i see WARN text when get capabilities.     WARN [wms.capabilities] - Map output format application/xml does not include mine type in output format names. Will be excluded from capabilities document.  No idea what its mean.

Comment: But i think its not problem couse if i write `test = new OpenLayers.Bounds(6753510.91, 7726958.60, 6756157.63, 7736434.96);    test__=test.transform(new OpenLayers.Projections("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projections("EPSG:4326"))`  And meters not transform im lon lat.